# PyDev Custom Interpreter Script doesn't Read Env Variables

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, pydev

I have a custom python interpreter defined in the script element of the **`InterpreterInfo`**. I also define some environment variables there, and I see them when I look at the interpreter info in the PyDev UI.

The interpreter executable is a shell script (`tcsh`) which wraps a python interpreter. It works fine, except it can't see the environment variables set for the interpreter. I thought these would be set in the environment of the executable script, but they're not. Is there a way I can pass variables defined for the interpreter info into the interpreter's executable script?

edit:

When any PyDev project is added to the workspace, I modify the script element so that it replaces the path to the python interpreter with a shell script that wraps the python interpreter. Here's the Java code, with exception handling elided.

```java
private static InterpreterInfo createInterpreterInfo(String interpreter, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        final File script = PydevPlugin.getScriptWithinPySrc("interpreterInfo.py");
        Tuple<String, String> outTup;
        outTup = new SimplePythonRunner().runAndGetOutputWithInterpreter(interpreter, script.getCanonicalPath(), null, null, null, monitor, "UTF-8");

        String interpreterXml = outTup.o1;
        String replacedInterpreterXml  = interpreterXml;

        //substitute the script for the <executable> element in the XML string
        String executableStartTag = "<executable>";
        String executableEndTag = "</executable>";
        int executableElementStart = interpreterXml.indexOf(executableStartTag) + executableStartTag.length();  
        int executableElementEnd = interpreterXml.indexOf(executableEndTag);

        replacedInterpreterXml = interpreterXml.substring(0, executableElementStart) + interpreter + interpreterXml.substring(executableElementEnd);

        // Add an environment variable
        String xmlEndTag = "</xml>";
        int xmlEndElementStart = replacedInterpreterXml.indexOf(xmlEndTag);  

        replacedInterpreterXml = replacedInterpreterXml.substring(0, xmlEndElementStart) +
                "\n<env_var>" +
                SOME_VARIABLE + "=" + ENV_VAR_VALUE +
                "</env_var>\n" +
                replacedInterpreterXml.substring(xmlEndElementStart);

        return InterpreterInfo.fromString(replacedInterpreterXml, false);
    }
```

The wrapper script then does some environment setup and calls the python interpreter with a command string. When the interpreter returns the script does environment teardown. The script is unable to find the environment variables set on the `InterpreterInfo`, either by looking in the shell environment or by having the python interpreter query its environment.

Here's a representation of the wrapper shell script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

#redirect output to avoid corrupting output to `InterpreterInfo`
echo Env variable SOME_VARIABLE = $SOME_VARIABLE > /log/file #throws error because SOME_VARIABLE is not set
python -c "import os;print os.environ['SOME_VARIABLE']" > /log/file #no value set for SOME_VARIABLE

do_environment_setup

python $*

do_environment_cleanup
```

Comment: How are you trying to do it? any command line you should share?

Comment: See the edit in the question for a further explanation and code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, the typo was in the post but not in the actual script, since of course I used a different variable name (there are actually three of them). I always use bash when it's up to me. My project is supporting a dated library that requires tcsh. I'm not using that library *for* my project, in which case I could use something else in its place. Rather my project is providing an IDE for the library, so I don't have the choice to avoid tcsh.